# Removing Invalid Characters from XML within XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, regex, replace, taglib

I am trying to write music Tags into an XML, but it fails on invalid chars, I have tried doing a replace but I can't seem to get the syntex right.

```
            //string pattern = "[\\~#%&*{}/:<>?|\"-]";
        //string replacement = "_";
        //Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
        //string sanitized = Regex.Replace(regEx.Replace(input, replacement), @"\s+", " ");

      XDocument baddoc = new XDocument
            (new XElement("Corrupt",
                badfiles.Select(badfile =>
                new XElement("File", badfile))));
            baddoc.Save("D:\\badfiles.xml");
      // foreach(string musicfile in musicfiles)
       //{ String Title = (TagLib.File.Create(musicfile).Tag.Title); }

      XDocument doc = new XDocument
          (new XElement("Songs",
               musicfiles.Select(musicfile=>
                new XElement("Song",
               (new XElement("Title", (TagLib.File.Create(musicfile).Tag.Title))),
               (new XElement("Path", (musicfile))),
               (new XElement("Artist", (TagLib.File.Create(musicfile).Tag.Performers)))
               ))));

      doc.Save("D:\\files.xml");
```

Comment: Are the characters within a CDATA section? What encoding are you using and what are the characters?

Comment: I tried to add a CDATA to it, but I got the same invalid char error durring debug. is there a seperate modifier for XElement that signifies CDATA? I just wrote it into the string itself.

Comment: Can you please define what "invalid characters" mean for you? Most characters are valid in XML - for most practical purposes all printable characters are "valid" (summary on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_Characters_in_XML or read XML specification on w3c)

Comment: @TankCR The `XElement` constructor has an overload which takes an `XCData` object. So usage would be: `XElement("FooElement", new XCData("string to embed in cdata"));`

Comment: the darn debugger doesn't tell me what Char its failing on, so I am giving the XCData a go and see what I get.

Comment: it would appear that I also have some NULL values that I need to handle as well, I will get back to this as soon as I get past that...

Comment: Please edit sample in your question to include just piece that causes the issue and add data (string values) that show what values you have and what you expect. Right now your sample feels like random chunk of half-commented-out code.

Comment: So I have been trying and trying and I can't seem to get the context right so that it replaces the '&' before the final save. http://pastebin.com/K17s9cDK

Comment: I ended up breaking it all out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up breaking it all out like this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
              XElement songsElement = new XElement("Songs");
              foreach(var musicfile in musicfiles)
              {
                  XElement songElement = new XElement("Song");
                  string songTitle;
                    try { songTitle = (TagLib.File.Create(musicfile).Tag.Title); }
                    catch { songTitle = "Missing"; }
                  uint songTNint;
                    try { songTNint = (TagLib.File.Create(musicfile).Tag.Track); }
                    catch { songTNint = 00; }
                    string songTN = songTNint.ToString();
                  string songPath = musicfile;
                  string songArtist;
                    try {songArtist = (TagLib.File.Create(musicfile).Tag.Performers[0]);}
                    catch {songArtist = "Missing";}
                  List<string> songGenres = new List<string>();
                  foreach (string Genre in (TagLib.File.Create(musicfile).Tag.Genres))
                  { songGenres.Add(Genre);}
                  string songGenre;
                  if (songGenres.Count > 1) { songGenre = (songGenres[0] + "/" + songGenres[1]); }
                  else { try { songGenre = songGenres[0]; } catch { songGenre = "Missing"; } }
                  songArtist = Regex.Replace(songArtist, @"[^\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty);
                  XElement titleElement = new XElement("Title",songTitle);
                  XElement tnElement = new XElement("TN", songTN);
                  XElement pathElement = new XElement("Path", musicfile);
                  XElement artistElement = new XElement("Artist",songArtist);
                  XElement genreElement = new XElement("Genre", songGenre);
                  songElement.Add(titleElement);
                  songElement.Add(tnElement);
                  songElement.Add(pathElement);
                  songElement.Add(artistElement);
                  songElement.Add(genreElement);
                  songsElement.Add(songElement);
              }
```